# Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.and } from ProcessRecordrequires com.sec.android.app.factorymode.permission.KEYSTRING

Tags: android

I have created app and uploaded the app in the Market.I Logged into My developer console there i find the some crash as shown below ,

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.android.settings/.BatteryInfo } from ProcessRecord{42696e78 27843:agm.bsp.battery/u0a132} (pid=27843, uid=10132) requires com.sec.android.app.factorymode.permission.KEYSTRING
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1930)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1415)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3446)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3407)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3617)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3585)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:283)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:160)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:468)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:126)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My Manifest file:

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

  <!--   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" >

    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" >
    </uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<meta-data android:value="a151c2fce086d57" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />
    <meta-data android:value="true" android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/settings_title"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DashboardActivity"
            android:label="@string/launcher_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/> 

        <service
            android:name=".BatteryNotifierService"
            android:label="BatteryNotifierService" />

        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
        <receiver
            android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="agm.bsp.battery.PowerSaverActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Can any one help me.
Thank You.

Comment: Are you trying to start the `com.android.settings/.BatteryInfo` activity from your app? If not, this stack trace has nothing to do with your app.

Comment: Can you post the code for this intent you are trying to send? Are you trying to interact with this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=agm.bsp.battery)?

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks .I'm not starting the com.android.settings/.BatteryInfo activity.Is there any way to prevent this issues.

Comment: @QuentinSwain Thanks for reply.Can you please give the More because i didn't understand .I'm Interacting with that app only .

Comment: "Thanks .I'm not starting the com.android.settings/.BatteryInfo activity" -- according to the stack trace, the `agm.bsp.battery` is trying to start that activity. Your manifest indicates that your app has related code in it (`agm.bsp.battery.PowerSaverActivity`). So, perhaps you should check again to see whether or not you are trying to start that activity. Or, perhaps some library you are using is trying to start that activity.

Comment: What @CommonsWare said is right. Double check your code or you would need to post more information. It looks like your intent is trying to interact with a component that requires this `com.sec.android.app.factorymode.permission.KEYSTRING` permission.

Comment: @QuentinSwain More Information means.

Comment: A dump from logcat in addition to your stack trace, or if you are willing to post the code you are using to generate the intent.

Comment: @QuentinSwain If i Gave this  com.sec.android.app.factorymode.permission.KEYSTRING  permission will it work ?

Comment: in theory it should. That's what the stack trace primarily complains about so if you declare it in your manifest it should work. I have never seen that permission before though. You could always try and see what happens?

Comment: I'm seeing this same crash report starting intent "com.android.settings/.RadioInfo". Turns out that stock Samsung ROMs don't support that activity and raise a SecurityException calling for "com.sec.android.app.factorymode.permission.KEYSTRING".  Adding that permission does nothing though since that activity doesn't exist on Samsung phones.

Comment: @pmont Thank you for your valuable Information...

Comment: cmp=com.android.settings/.Display too